# AJAX doesn't show image but shows the PHP database query

Tags: php, ajax, image, html

Can anybody help with this I'm having trouble showing the image from a page but the sql query shows the sting just fin this is the code

**CODE FOR THE JQUERY**(Note: this is a click then load into a targeted spot)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Not IE
                } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
                    alert("Your browser doesn't support the XmlHttpRequest object.  Better upgrade to Firefox.");
                }
            }           
            var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();     
            function catia() {
                if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
                    receiveReq.open("GET", 'products/product-display-catia.php', true);
                    receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleCatia; 
                    receiveReq.send(null);
                }           
            }
            function handleCatia() {
                if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;

                }
            }
            </script>
```

This is the code for the page that the jquery tries to show
**CODE**

```
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID='6'");                
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))                    
                                {echo"
                                        <tr><td><img src='image/1361663812.png'></td></tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan='2'><img src='image/".$row['Logo']."'></td>
                                        </tr>       

                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td>Product: ".$row['Product']."   </td>
                                        </tr>
```

And this is the code for the page where the navigation for the ajax is
**code**

```
<div id='navi'>
        </br>
        </br>
            <ol>
                <li><details>
                    <summary>Products</summary>
                        <table align='center'>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href='javascript:catia();'>Catia</a></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>                    
                    </details></li>
            </ol>
     </div>
```

And this is the body where the ajax will display the page
**Code**

```
<div id='bod' align="center">

        <div id='main'>a
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Whats the error or code its showing instead of image?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer yet as I don't really have enough information to go on.

I assume you're having trouble with this line:

```
<td colspan='2'><img src='image/".$row['Logo']."'></td>
```

If so, please make the following modification and let me know what it prints out:

```
<td colspan='2'>##".$row['Logo']."##<img src='image/".$row['Logo']."'></td>
```

Note that I added `##".$row['Logo']."##` so that you can see what `$row['Logo']` contains.

Comment: no that line is working fine when i access it but when i try to show it in the index using ajax/javascript to call it and show the information in that everything works except the picture which does not load properly i think i need to open it using the  receiveReq.open() in the coding for the ajax function but im not really sure for this and also thanks for your time in trying to help me!